# Access parent's "belongs_to" object from child (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a CRUD and I have Books, Chapters and Scenes.

When creating a new Scene, I wish to show the parent Chapter title and it's parent Book title as a breadcrumb.

How could I set the 'scenes' controller to be able to do this?

Here's my implementation:

**"Book" Model (app/models/book.rb)**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :stories

end
```

**"Chapter" Model (app/models/chapter.rb)**

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :scenes
    belongs_to :book

end
```

**"Scene" Model (app/models/scene.rb)**

```
class Scene < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :chapter

end
```

Comment: Please add your current implementation to the question. There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: Kindly add your schema or model's associations for better electrification of question.

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough information. I'll be clearer in the next questions. @sergio-rivas answer was what I needed, thank you all for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have:

- A `scene` `belongs_to` a `chapter`
- A `chapter` `belongs_to` a `book`

So if you have the `scene` variable, you can access doing 
`scene.chapter.title` and `scene.chapter.book.title`

Comment: Thank you very much, @sergio-rivas! That's what I needed! And thank you for the answer's formatting, it'll help me in the next questions and answers :)